# How to join SQL tables in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, h2

How can I bind author_firstName and author_lastName from class Author with class Book? I work with h2 database, author_id and book_id are primary keys , I use postman

```
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "book_title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "book_genre")
    private String genre;
    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Author")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="author_id")
    private int authorId;
    
    @Column(name="author_firstName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="author_lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="author_birth")
    private Date birth;

}
```

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on JPA, e.g. [this one over at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/learn-jpa-hibernate) or the [official JavaEE documentation](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-intro.html).

Comment: So I need to use ManyToOne relationship?

Comment: Usually book can have multiple authors and any author can have multiple books. So its `many-to-many`. But you can say its `one-to-many` depending on your application.

Comment: yes you are right, so I will use many-to many but I have Set<> and it can`t be represent in JSON in Postman?

Comment: Its a collection, you represent it as list of object in JSON. Like this `[ {"authorId": 1},{ "authorId": 2} ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of using String arguments to `author`, you should convert this as a @ManyToOne relationship:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Author")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="author_id")
    private int authorId;
    
    @Column(name="author_firstName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="author_lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="author_birth")
    private Date birth;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books;

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "book_title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "book_genre")
    private String genre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

}
```

With this model, you will be able to fetch data from any entrypoint, from books from an author (books written by a specific author), or, author who has books (collection of books written by an author).

You can use default implementation of `findAll` Spring Data JPA implementation (will join automatically both tables if you use EAGER fetch type), or, build your own JPQL:

`FROM Author a FETCH JOIN a.books b WHERE a.id = b.author`.

This will help the legibility of your code and improve your database data normalization.